# How to change special signs for ASCII signs?

Tags: python, pandas

do you know how to change special signs like 'łźą' for ASCII signs 'lza' ? I try to use unidecode as the internet suggested.

```
import pandas as pd
from unidecode import unidecode

history = pd.read_csv('history.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')

print(unidecode(history))
```

but This is the DataFrame, and I have an error like that: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to apply the function for all of the series you want to mangle. If you know the series (columns) `foo`, `bar` and `quux` contain text to "fix",

```
import pandas as pd
from unidecode import unidecode

history = pd.read_csv('history.csv')
for col in ('foo', 'bar', 'quux'):
    history[col] = history[col].apply(unidecode)
```